# Accessing XML elements with LINQ using VB.net (not C#)

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I am trying to learn how to search XML trees with LINQ using VB.net. I've found some very helpful posts for C#, but none for VB.net

- [How would I use LINQ to XML to get the value from example XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015106/how-would-i-use-linq-to-xml-to-get-the-value-from-example-xml)
- [Getting a set of elements using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526719/getting-a-set-of-elements-using-linq)
- [How to get elements value with Linq To XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825714/how-to-get-elements-value-with-linq-to-xml)

I want to get the inputlocation for the process where name = "MyProcess1" Based on the example links above, I have been trying code like this:

```
   Dim inputLocation As String = xdocument.Descendants("Configurations").Descendants("process").First(Function(c) c.Element("name").Value = "MyProcess1").Element("inputLocation").Value
```

But the code is not returning any values. here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configurations>
 <process>
<name>MyProcess1</name>
<inputLocation> inputPath
</inputLocation>
<outputLocation> outputPath1
</outputLocation>
  </process>
  <process>
<name>MyProcess2</name>
<inputLocation> inputPath2
</inputLocation>
<outputLocation>outputPath2
</outputLocation>
  </process>
</Configurations>
```

Comment: Try this:
Dim inputLocation As String = xdocument.Descendants("Configurations").Descendants("process").First(Function(c) c.Element("name").Value.Equals("MyProcess1")).Element("inputLocation").Value.Trim()

Comment: Great :). I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim inputLocation As String = xdocument.Descendants("Configurations").Descendants("process").First(Function(c) c.Element("name").Value.Equals("MyProcess1")).Element("inputLocation").Value.Tri‌​m();
```

It basically just trims the ***\n*** character from the end of the value returned :). I've inserted **Equals()** instead of **=** just in case, but both should work :).